# Как спарсить значения из result[i]

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, range

Вспомогательные функции. Находятся в модуле `helper`

```
async def product_key(title, amount, payments):
    width = 57
    if amount >= 1000 and amount <= 1000000:
        amount //= 1000
        amount = f'{amount}K'
    else:
        amount = str(amount)
    len_title = width - len(amount) - len(str(payments)) - 3
    title = title[0: len_title] + '...'
    text = f'{payments} | {amount} | {title}'
    return text

async def postgresql(sql):
    connect_postgresql = await asyncpg.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
    await connect_postgresql.execute(sql)
    if 'SELECT' in sql:
        return await connect_postgresql.fetch(sql)
    await connect_postgresql.close()
```

Это основной код, который достает с БД данные и пытается 'разложить всё по полочкам'

```
key = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
result = await helper.postgresql(f"SELECT id, title, amount, payments FROM products;")
for i in range(1, 5):
   for tr in result[i]:
      print(result[i])
      print(tr)
      for id, title, amount, payments in tr:
          key.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=await helper.product_key(title, amount, payments), callback_data=id))

#Пагинация пока не работает
key.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='<<<', callback_data=' '),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='125 / 140', callback_data=' '),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='>>>', callback_data=' '))
```

Вывод на `print(result[i])`:

```
<Record id=702 title='lacus at velit vivamus vel nulla eget eros elementum pellentesque' amount=2 payments='21,00 ₽'>
```

Ввод на `print(tr)`:

```
702
```

Вопрос в том как спарсить значения из `print(result[i])` в значения `id, title, amount, payments`
А вот то что я хочу увидеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос очень очевидный

```
async def show_products(callback, state):
    key = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    start = 32 #пример
    end = 49   #пример
    result = await helper.postgresql(f"SELECT id, title, amount, payments FROM products;")
    for i in range(start, end):

        #Вот здесь решение вашего вопроса
        id, title, amount, payments = result[i]

        key.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=await helper.product_key(title, amount, payments), callback_data=id))
    text = 'Какой-то текст'
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, text, reply_markup=key)
```